# Intermediate Fields between $k(x,y)$ and $k(x^p,y^p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$ and let $x, y$ be algebraically independent
over $k$. Prove the following:

1-$k(x, y)$ has degree $p^2$ over $k(x^p, y^p).$

2-There exist infinitely many extensions between $k(x, y)$ and $k(x^p, y^p).$

I showed that the set $S=\{x^iy^j \mid 0 \leq i,j \leq p-1\}$ is a basis for $k(x,y)$ over the field $k(x^p,y^p) $, but can I do the other part? What will happen if there are only finitely many intermmediate fields between these two?

Also I wonder how these infinitely many intermediate field look like? I thought the only fields in between these two will be of the form $k(x^k,y^l)$ and that all. I thought I would have a maximum p^2 intermediate fields. This problem is from lang's algebra

Comment: Do you know the primitive element theorem?

Comment: yes, I do know primitive element theorem

Comment: Anything unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your examples of $k(x^k, y^l)$ don't really make sense. For instance, if $p=5$ then would $k(x^2, y^2)$ contain $k(x^5, y^5)$? You'd probably have to have meant $k(x^p, y^p, x^k, y^l)$, but these aren't uniquely determined by $k, l$ as that field equals $k(x^p, y^p, x^{p-k}, y^{p-l})$. Also, there are concrete examples of fields other than these, such as $k(x^p, y^p, x+y)$.

Anyways, let's recall the primitive element theorem. It says that a finite extension of fields $K/F$ has finitely many intermediate fields if and only if $K = F(a)$ for some $a \in K$. We say that $K/F$ is a simple extension and that $a$ is a primitive element. Since you already showed that $[k(x, y) : k(x^p, y^p)] = p^2$, if there were finitely many intermediate fields here the primitive element theorem would tell us that the extension is simple, i.e. that $k(x, y) = k(x^p, y^p)(a)$.

I will show, however, that this extension is not simple. Indeed, I will show that $[k(x^p, y^p)(a) : k(x^p, y^p)] \leq p$ for all $a \in k(x, y)$. Indeed, take such an $a$. We can write $a = \frac{f}{g}$ with $f, g \in k[x, y]$. Because $k$ has characteristic $p$, we have that $f^p, g^p \in k[x^p, y^p]$ so $a^p = \frac{f^p}{g^p} \in k(x^p, y^p)$. Hence, $t^p - a^p$ is a (nonzero) polynomial in $k(x^p, y^p)[t]$. Of course, this polynomial has a root at $a$. Thus, the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $k(x^p, y^p)$ must divide $t^p - a^p$ and must therefore have degree at most $p$. Hence, $[k(x^p, y^p)(a) : k(x^p, y^p)] \leq p < p^2 = [k(x, y) : k(x^p, y^p)]$ so the extension is not simple. In conclusion, the primitive element theorem then tells us that there must be infinitely many intermediate fields to the extension $k(x, y)/k(x^p, y^p)$.

Answer (score 4):

$$k(x^p,y^p,y+ x^{pn+1}),\qquad n\in \Bbb{Z}$$ are infinitely many pairwise distinct intermediate fields, this is because $$[k(x^p,y^p,y+ x^{pn+1}):k(x^p,y^p)] = p$$ and $$k(x^p,y^p,y+ x^{pn+1},y+ x^{pm+1}) = k(x^p,y^p,y+ x^{pn+1},x(x^{pn}-x^{mp}))$$
$$ = k(x^p,y^p,y+x^{pn+1},x)=k(x,y)$$ has degree $p^2$ over $k(x^p,y^p)$.

Comment: why are the fields distinct?

Comment: ? It is explained in my answer, if $E=F$ then $[EF:K]=[F:K]$ @permutation_matrix